# Entity Framework Core DBContext Datamodel as variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, dbcontext, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am trying to create a generic list feed with a REST API service in ASP.NET Core 2 using Entity Framework Core.  I want to bring in a string that will determine what table is used for the feed.  I am having trouble initializing a generic DBContext.DataModel variable that I can assign my _context.Model to for my linq command later.  This will be called by my controller.

```
public class ServiceRepository : IServiceRepository

    private readonly MyDataDbContext _context

    public ServiceRepository(MyDataDbContext context){
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<IEmumerable<GenericFeedResource>> GetFeed(string feedType){
        var feed = new ???  (What object to use?)

        switch(feedType)
            {
            case: "Feed1": feed = _context.Model1;
                break;
            ...
            }

        var data = await feed.Where(f => f.Inactive == false).ToListAync();

        ... var result = formatting of data

        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the context has a set of tables that are each for object types that implement the same base class you can use the `.Cast<T>()` extension.

```
IEmumerable<GenericFeedResource> feed;

switch(feedType)
{
    case: "Feed1": 
        feed = _context.Model1.Cast<GenericFeedResource>();
        break;
}
```

Comment: This does not work because I cannot call my context.model object below when I am doing my LINQ command of
    var data = await feed.Where(f => f.Inactive == false).ToListAync();  I need the object type to initialize so I can use it in a EF call later in the code.

Comment: As long as all the code paths before this point initialise the value. The compiler will be ok. Otherwise: `IEmumerable<GenericFeedResource> feed = new List<GenericFeedResource>();` will work to.

Comment: Actually the feed should be a single object and not an array of objects.  The data variable below will be the array.

Comment: Ok.  I am done editing your answer now and this is working in my code.  Got me on the right track though.